# Can you convert results from input type date and input type time to seconds since epoch

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a routing system and want to add a function so you can enter a start date and time through an HTML form, then JavaScript will add the route time to it and display it on the page.

However I'm having a bit of trouble with getting the date and time in the right format.

Comment: Something like `new Date('2018-12-31T01:32:00').getTime()/1000;` ?

Comment: @NickParsons Thank you, I was having trouble with the formatting of the datestring But This helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the time in seconds with this:

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.getTime() / 1000;
```

Comment: Docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime